# Como o composer se comporta quanto a atualização de pacotes?

Tags: composer

Tenho a versão `^1.0.0` de um pacote. Bem como `autoload` do prefixo `"\\Empresa\\Pacote": "lib/"`.

Caso eu venha a renomear o diretório `lib/` para `src/`. O certo seria disponibilizar o pacote como `v1.0.1` ou `v1.1.0`?

Além disso, ao renomear desta forma, isso iria prejudicar atualização nos clientes que já possuem o pacote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Caso eu venha a renomear o diretório `lib/` para `src/`. O certo seria disponibilizar o pacote como `v1.0.1` ou `v1.1.0`?

Pode ser `v1.0.1` seguindo a sequencia normal do seu pacote e por ser uma correção, não esqueça de atualizar essa nova versão em seu [github](/questions/tagged/github) ou ***local*** de armazenamento de pacote. Quando tiver uma grande mudança, a versão recomendada seria a `v2.0.0` e pequenas correções continua na numeração com acrescimento de **1** e se for adição de novas funcionalidade que nada compromete as versões seria `v1.1.0`.

**Resumindo** no seu caso seria `v1.0.1`

> Além disso, ao renomear desta forma, isso iria prejudicar atualização nos clientes que já possuem o pacote?

Quem baixar a nova versão não terá problema algum, porque, o [`composer`](https://getcomposer.org/) dá um comando para recarregar os pacotes (se ele quiser baixar a antiga, a pasta ainda será a `lib/`). Vale lembrar que seu pacote terá duas versões com uma singela mudança de *pasta de armazenamento* (correção), realmente, a `src/` seria um padrão adotado por vários pacotes.

Quando se lança novas versões as alterações são aplicadas na hora da instalação.

No site do [github](/questions/tagged/github) tem um texto:

**Inglês**

> Tagging suggestions It’s common practice to prefix your version names
>   with the letter v. Some good tag names might be v1.0 or v2.3.4.
>
> If the tag isn’t meant for production use, add a pre-release version
>   after the version name. Some good pre-release versions might be
>   v0.2-alpha or v5.9-beta.3.

**Tradução:**

> Sugestões de marcação É prática comum prefixar seus nomes de versão
>   com a letra v. Alguns nomes de tag boa podem ser v1.0 ou v2.3.4.
>
> Se a tag não for usada para produção, adicione uma versão de
>   pré-lançamento após o nome da versão. Algumas boas versões de
>   pré-lançamento podem ser v0.2-alpha ou v5.9-beta.3.

Ou seja,

Se for um `release` (**lançamento**)

```
v1.0.2 //último lançamento geralmente usado para correções
v1.0.1
v1.0.0
```

Se for `production` (**produção**)

```
v0.0.2-alpha //última produção
v0.0.1-alpha
```

Além dessa explicação básica, exite um texto em [Semantic Versioning 2.0.0](http://semver.org/), que pode esclarecer suas duvidas.

***Exemplo:***

```
v1.2.0 //isso é um mero exemplo.
```

> O número 1 é o MAJOR (alterações da sua `API` que causam incompatibilidade com as antigas)
>
> O número 2 é o MINOR (adição de funcionalidades que são compatíveis com a atual versão)
>
> O número 0 é o PATCH (correções, `bugs`)

**Inglês**

> `MAJOR` version when you make incompatible API changes,
>
> `MINOR` version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner, and
>
> `PATCH` version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes.

**Tradução:**

> `MAJOR` quando você faz alterações incompatíveis da `API`,
>
> `MINOR` versão quando você adiciona funcionalidade de uma maneira compatível com versões anteriores e
>
> `PATCH` quando você faz correções de bugs compatíveis com versões anteriores.

---

*Referencias:*

- [Dependency Manager for PHP](https://getcomposer.org/)
- [Semantic Versioning 2.0.0](http://semver.org/)
- [Creating Releases](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-releases/)
- [Working with Tags](https://help.github.com/articles/working-with-tags/)